# I can see the list result [x,y] with print command by using looping x and y. However, to create a csv file with header x and y?

Tags: python-2.7, list

My code:

```
for i in range (0,5,1):
    for j in range (0,5,2):   
        coord = [i,j]
        print coord
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please edit to add more details.

Comment: Soffy for the confusion. This is the result from my code. I want to export an csv file with header x y                                                                          x  y                                                                                                           [0, 0]
[0, 2]
[0, 4]
[1, 0]
[1, 2]
[1, 4]
[2, 0]
[2, 2]
[2, 4]
[3, 0]
[3, 2]
[3, 4]
[4, 0]
[4, 2]
[4, 4]

Comment: Have you looked at the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

Comment: I did but it only output the only one x, y

Comment: I tried to add this code on the end:                                                              df = pd.DataFrame(coord)
        df.to_csv(path + '/Coordinate.csv')

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks!